# How can i set right iam policy in gcp with an service account

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dns

I have a problem with GCP iam policy cross project on the dns API (perhaps other api entry).
For gcp management i use gcloud command and terraform.

Check my setup :
A first gcp project : myproject-cloud. This project host a dns managed zone.

A second project (akecld-test-demo), with an account service. This account is used with terraform to create instance, disk etc... no problem with that. I play with gcloud to confirm wrong setup with dns api.

When i want add (or list) an entry in the dns zone (setup and hold in the first project) i have 403 error.

```
gcloud   --account=provisioner@akecld-test-demo.iam.gserviceaccount.com  dns  managed-zones list --project=myproject-cloud
API [dns.googleapis.com] not enabled on project [xxxxxxxxx]....
```

dns api works with a service account who've created in the first project, but not a service account hosted in other project.

I have added iam policy:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding myproject-cloud --member="serviceAccount:provisioner@akecld-test-demo.iam.gserviceaccount.com" --role="roles/dns.admin"
```

I don't find the right roles or policies to add..

Comment: FYI : You need to enable DNS API in second project, not only the first... It works now!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable DNS API in second project, not only the first... 
It works now!!